# Problem with libraries and Mingw-gcc to cross-compile Win32 code on Linux

Tags: linux, winapi, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile some C/C++ programs I've written on Linux for Windows. I've had a lot of experience using both GCC and MSVC.

Normally when compiling a program using gcc, one would use the -l linker argument to specify a library to link against. It seems that this does not work properly when using the MingW-gcc linker.

GCC version:
`i586-mingw32msvc-gcc (GCC) 4.4.4`

When linking a program that uses (for example, GTK+ or libpng, libz, etc.), using something like:

`i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -mwindows -L/opt/xcompile-win32/lib -lmylib -lmylib2 myprog.o -o myprog.exe`

Gives numerous errors about undefined references to the library functions. However, if I specify the libraries as additional objects like this:

`i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -mwindows -L/opt/xcompile-win32/lib /opt/xcompile-win32/lib/libmylib.a /opt/xcompile-win32/lib/libmylib2.a myprog.o -o myprog.exe`

Everything works fine and the resulting program works great! My question is: Is there a way I can get the normal -l library arguments to work correctly? This method seems a bit cumbersome! I can't seem to find anything online which addresses this issue. Thanks!

**Edit:**

To clarify: the order of the library arguments on the command-line makes no difference. Also, the program compiles just fine on Linux (gcc) using only the -l arguments. Actual command below:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc  -mwindows -o win32/vmclient.exe win32/gtk_test.o \
-L/opt/xcompile-win32/lib -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 \
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lcairo -lpng12 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig \
-lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0

win32/gtk_test.o:gtk_test.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `_gtk_init_abi_check'
```

(and a bunch of similar errors). The program compiles fine for Win32 (using i586-mingw32msvc-gcc) when directly referencing the .a library files in the exact same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the order of the command line arguments. If library linked with the `-l` the linker will only take the object modules needed to satisfy any unresolved referece seen so far. From `info ld`, option `-l`:

> If the archive defines a
>        symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before
>        the archive on the command line, the linker will include the
>        appropriate file(s) from the archive.  However, an undefined
>        symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will not
>        cause the linker to search the archive again.

But when you write the full path of the library it is linked wholly.

So to compile your program simply write:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -mwindows myprog.o -o myprog.exe \
    -L/opt/xcompile-win32/lib -lmylib -lmylib2
```

With the libraries at the end.

BTW, if I'm not mistaken this behavior is no different in the native linux compiler.

**Edit:**

Replying to your edit, you forgot to add a few libraries to your compiler command. You are missing `-lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0`.

Personally I find it much more convenient to use the `pkg-config` tool. When cross-compiling it is just as easy as exporting `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/op/xcompile-win32/pkgconfig`.

In linux it works fine maybe because the missing libraries are brought in automatically by `NEEDED` records in the other libraries.

Comment: Thanks, rodrigo. I guess I should have mentioned that the above program compiles just fine natively on Linux (I'm aware of the library ordering requirements-- I should have give a real example). Check out the revised question-- I added a bit of clarity.